# Reliable way to get PID of piped background process

Tags: bash, background-process, job-control, jobs

I need to retrieve the PID of a process piped into another process that together are spawned as a background job in bash. Previously I simply relied on `pgrep`, but as it turns out there can be a delay of >2s before `pgrep` is able to find the process:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd1 | cmd2 &
pid=$(pgrep cmd1) # emtpy in about 1/10
```

I found that some common recommendations for this problem are using process substitution rather than a simple pipe (`cmd1 >(cmd2) & pid=$!`) or using the `jobs` builtin.
Process substitution runs an entire subshell (for the entire runtime), so I would rather use `jobs` for now, but I want to avoid making the same mistake twice...

Can I 100% depend on `jobs` to be aware of both processes if I perform the lookup immediately after spawning them?

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd1 | cmd2 &
pid=$(jobs -p %cmd1) # 10/10?
```

This is probably on account of running jobs in background, or maybe a quirk of `set -x`, but the following example usually lists the executed commands in any which order. The `jobs` output **appears** to be correct so far, but I want to entirely rule out the possibility that `jobs` could be executed *before* the jobs have been started (or at least that `jobs` will fail to list the two processes)!?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
tail -f /dev/null | cat &
jobs -l
kill %tail
```

Example:

```
+ jobs -l
[1]+ 2802325 Running                 tail -f /dev/null
     2802326                       | cat &
+ tail -f /dev/null
+ kill %tail
```

Likewise, in the process substitution case, can I rely on `pid=$!` to always work? It is designed to "expand to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command" after all?

Comment: Based on a fairly recent experience, I wouldn't rely on jobs fixing your issue. I found sketchy behaviour from `jobs -p` when called from a subshell, where it would fail to notice the last background job ending.  The workaround I came up with was to run `jobs >/dev/null` immediately before `pids=($(jobs -p))`.  This seems to be rock solid, but I'd love to know what's going on if someone else has some insight.

Comment: from `info bash` : 3.2.3, "_Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell, which is
a separate process (*note Command Execution Environment::)_". and 3.2.4, "_If a command is terminated by the control operator '&', the shell
executes the command asynchronously in a subshell._"

Comment: Yes, and `$(jobs)` is also executed in a subshell. But are there any guarantees w.r.t. execution order? Can `$(...)` run before `cmd1` and `cmd2` are spawned asynchronously if the scheduler wants to be funny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a background job is a pipeline of the form `cmd1 | cmd2`, it's still a single background job. There's no way to know when `cmd1` starts.

Each `&` creates one background job. As soon as `cmd &` returns, the shell is aware of that background job: `cmd & jobs` lists `cmd`. `cmd & pid=$!` sets `pid` to the process ID that runs `cmd`.

The pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2` creates two more subprocesses: one to run `cmd1` and one to run `cmd2`. Both processes are children of the subprocess that runs the background job. Here's how the process tree looks like for `bash -c '{ sleep 123 | sleep 456; } & jobs -p; sleep 789'`:

```
 PID PPID CMD
 268  265  |   \_ bash -c { sleep 123 | sleep 456; } & sleep 789
 269  268  |       \_ bash -c { sleep 123 | sleep 456; } & sleep 789
 270  269  |       |   \_ sleep 123
 271  269  |       |   \_ sleep 456
 272  268  |       \_ sleep 789
```

268 is the original bash process. 269 is the background job that `jobs -p` prints. 270 and 271 are the left- and right-hand sides of the pipe, both children of the main process of the background job (269).

The version of bash I tested with (5.0.17 on Linux) optimizes `cmd1 | cmd2 &` without braces. In that case, the left-hand side of the pipe runs in the same process as the background job:

```
 PID PPID CMD
 392  389  |   \_ bash -c sleep 123 | sleep 456 & jobs -p; sleep 789
 393  392  |       \_ sleep 123
 394  392  |       \_ sleep 456
 395  392  |       \_ sleep 789
```

You can't rely on this behavior to be stable across versions of bash, or possibly even across platforms, distributions, libc versions, etc.

`jobs -p %cmd1` looks for a job whose code starts with `cmd1`. What it finds is `cmd1 | cmd2`. `jobs -p %?cmd2` finds the same job¹. There's no way to access the process IDs running `cmd1` and `cmd2` through built-in features of bash.

If you need to know for sure that `cmd1` has started, use a process substitution.

```
cmd1 >(cmd2)
```

You don't get to know when `cmd2` starts and ends.

If you need to know when `cmd1` and `cmd2` start and end, you need to make them both jobs, and have them communicate through a named pipe.

```
tmp=$(mktemp -d) # Remove this in cleanup code
mkfifo "$tmp/pipe"
cmd1 >"$tmp/pipe" & pid1=$!
cmd2 <"$tmp/pipe" & pid2=$!
…
```

The `jobs` command is not very useful in scripts. Use `$!` to remember PIDs of background jobs.

¹  <sub>Or at least it should. My version complains about an ambiguous job spec, which has to be a bug since it's saying that despite there being only a single job.</sub>

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch, that's the thorough explanation I was looking for :-)
A bit of an aside, but do you happen to know how traps are handled when process substitution spawns a subshell? I hope only the parent will be running them? (I guess the signal is typically sent to the parent's PID, not the child's, so should be safe?)

Comment: @emike Subshells do not inherit traps. The only thing they inherit is if a signal is ignored: `trap "" INT` ignores SIGINT in the main shell process and its subshells, but with `trap cleanup INT`, SIGINT kills the subshells and runs `cleanup` in the main shell processes (I think guaranteed in this order if the signal is sent atomically to all the processes involved).

Comment: By the way, the reference I was working off mentions that `jobs -p %cmd1` looks for a job *beginning* with `cmd1`, `%?cmd1` would be *containing*. But that probably doesn't change your statement.

Comment: I happen to be working in a read-only file system which does not allow me to create named pipes. Can you think of any problems if instead I allocate a r/w file descriptor on `<(:)` (ie empty file in pipefs) and use that "like" a named pipe?
Example: `exec {fd}<> <(:); cmd1 >&${fd} & pid1=$!; cmd2 <&${fd} & pid2=$!; ...; exec {fd}>&-`

Comment: @emike That looks about right. Alternatively, you might be able to use a coprocess, but bash has a major limitation that it only supports one coprocess at a time. You can run `coproc cmd1 { cmd1 </dev/null; } cmd2 <${cmd1[1]}`

Comment: Great explanation, thank you